# CI Session Destroy after redirection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three parallel websites on a single IP and all are using CI. So, I am facing a problem while login process. When I trying to login it will destroy all my set session and resultant I am not able to login into my admin panel.

Please suggest on it and thanks in advance.

Comment: People are not god to know whats going on your code. Paste your code for help.

Comment: First thought that pops into my head is maybe a name conflict. But yeah, without any code, we will not be able to help you.

Comment: Please paste your code. May be you have same name for all cookie names ```$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';``` in your config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the situation I figured out the problem. The problem was in the configuration file and with the permissions to the system folder.